# MySQL completely clearing cache

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, caching, iis

I am building a website in ASP.NET which is connected to a MySQL database.

I have a complex query and I have noticed that first time after a I re-start MySQL this query is slow (5-8 sec), following happens almost immediately (< ~1 sec).

I thought this had to do with data being cached by MySQL, so I tried to do a 
`FLUSH QUERY CACHE` and even a `RESET QUERY CACHE` - but this seems not to affect the response-time of the query.

Any suggestion on how I can completely clear the cache without actually restarting the DB server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SQL_NO_CACHE option.

Example:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE id, name FROM customer;
```

For more information, check [the MySQL documentation for SQL Query Cache SELECT Options](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/query-cache-in-select.html)